# How do I figure out the specific coefficient of a dummy variable?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, linear

I have a linear regression model that aims to predict the quality of melon icecream (dependent variable) using the amount of sugar, melon powder, and vegetable oil.

The equation is as follows,

$$\text{Quality} = 0.6 + 0.02X_1 + 0.2X_2 + 0.15X_3$$

where $X_1$ is sugar, $X_2$ is melon powder and $X_3$ is vegetable oil.

Now, I added in a new categorical variable called "Spice" which shows if I added cinnamon or nutmeg. To make a dummy variable out of this, I dropped the nutmeg category.

The new equation is

$$\text{Quality} = 0.5 + 0.01X_1 + 0.4X_2 + 0.10X_3 - 0.1X_4$$

where $X_4$ is cinnamon.

Is there a way to figure out the coefficient of nutmeg if cinnamon was dropped instead from the information given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. The group specific intercept for "Spice" is 0.5 (intercept of baseline category, i.e. "Nutmeg") - 0.1 (difference between baseline and category indicated by the dummy variable) = 0.4. If you would have swapped coefficients in the way you describe, this would be your baseline intercept. That is, your intercept would be 0.4 in that case. You group specific intercept for "Nutmeg" is 0.5 (the intercept of the original model). This implies that your "Nutmeg" coefficient would equal 0.1, since the intercept + the coefficient*1 would have to add up to 0.5. Is that clear?